# Missing 407 when print Amstrong Number in C language

Tags: c, codeblocks

I use Code::Block 10.02 and When print Amstrong Number in C.I wait a result like this:

```
153
370
371
407
```

But It's only print:

```
153
370
371
```

This is my code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{

    int a,b,c;
    for  (a=1;a<=9;a++)
        for(b=0;b<=9;b++)
            for(c=0;c<=9;c++)
            {
                    if(pow(a,3)+pow(b,3)+pow(c,3)==100*a+10*b+c)
                           printf("\n%d%d%d",a,b,c);
            }

}
```

And this is my screen:  http://daynhauhoc.com/uploads/default/3011/9598a2ad2183198f.png

But, when i use this code, It's Work very well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{

    int a,b,c;
    for  (a=1;a<=9;a++)
        for(b=0;b<=9;b++)
            for(c=0;c<=9;c++)
            {
                    int d=pow(a,3)+pow(b,3)+pow(c,3);
                    int e=100*a+10*b+c;
                    if(d==e)
                           printf("\n%d%d%d",a,b,c);
            }

}
```

Someone tell me a explantion please?

Comment: Both versions print the same four results when compiled in MSVC.

Comment: Yep!, i tried in Python or online Compiler, Both work!, i can't believe code::block have problem. I don't know why

Comment: You have not flushed the terminal output with a trailing `\n` newline. Perhaps that will make a difference, although both versions neglect that.

Comment: Try `printf("%d%d%d\n",a,b,c) ` it might work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh i know why!! You use `pow(a,3)+pow(b,3)+pow(c,3)==100*a+10*b+c` However `pow()` return `double` you use `==` to determine whether the same float and integer.
Don't use `==` or `!=` between integer and float!

Comment: What is worth adding is that he is actually converting the power sum result with the  int d=pow(a,3)+pow(b,3)+pow(c,3); to the integer which makes it work in the other case. Nicely spotted.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely that the `pow ()` function is a floating-point function with rounding errors. So `pow (4, 3)` is not 64, but some number very very close to 64. You will be comparing 407 and a number that is very, very close to 407 and that will sometimes fail.

Instead of `pow (a, 3)`, just write `a*a*a`.

BTW. The rounding errors depend on the exact implementation of `pow`, which isn't exactly the same on every computer. So this number that is "very very close to 407" may be "just very slightly larger" on one computer, "just very slightly smaller" on another, and by coincidence it may be "exactly 407" on a third computer. Which explains why someone says "works for me" and someone else says "doesn't work".

BTW. By converting to int, your result is rounded *down* to an integer. So if one computer gets 407.000000000000000001, that is rounded down to 407, but if another computer gets 406.999999999999999999, that is rounded down to 406.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appear because `pow` is a function of double and it's some time not true, example:9999.99999 = 10e4.

A tip is use `powf`, it's pow for integer